# php some object properties yellow in syntax

Tags: php, syntax, properties

I know this may be a noob question, but I have searched and couldn't find a definitive explanation anywhere. I understand this may be part to do with the IDE syntax, as I use Aptana Studio.

I have noticed that some properties I access by doing this

```
$this->property
```

are coloured in yellow. Some of the properties are:

```
$this->mail

$this->hash

$this->key
```

etc... Why is that? I am assuming because it has something to do with the fact that they are names of php standard functions? Maybe I am wrong?

Also is it ok to use these as properties? for instance I wanted to build a custom mailer class and add some functions to it. Should I use a different naming convention or will there be repercussions later?

i.e.

```
class mail{

public $to = '';
public $subject = '';
public $message = '';
public $additonal_headers = '';
public $additional_parameters = '';

    public function send(){

       mail($this->to,$this->subject,$this->message,$this->additonal_headers,$this->additional_parameters);

    }
    public function something else(){
    // Something else
    }

}

$mail = new mail;
$mail->to = 'someone@somewhere';
$mail->send();
```

Hope I have been clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: No idea about your IDE, but since you don't actually HAVE properties called "mail" or hash" or "key" in your mail object, they're probably being flagged as undefined/unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of reserved PHP words:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

You are not using any of the reserved words so I think you are OK there, but as Marc B, mentioned you IDE might be letting you know about unused/undefined properties.